# R data.table - new column with ':=' and keep existing column

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to create a new column and keep (few) existing columns in the statement ? e.g. creation of "x" column and then keeping "x" and "mpg" column

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars)

dt[,x:=mpg]

dt[,.(x,mpg)]
```

Comment: Do you need to modify the original object as it can be dangerous if not being careful

Comment: I totally agree. It is not advisable to update the original object. I have a situation where minor savings in processing time will add value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do the replacement by reference, using `:=` then you can do

```
dt[, x:=mpg][, setdiff(colnames(dt), c('x', 'mpg')) := NULL]
```

Answer (score 1):

If we need it in a single step, instead of doing the `:=` to modify the original dataset, specify it with `=` inside `list` or `.(`

```
dt[,.(x = mpg, mpg)]
```

---

Or if it necessary to create the column in original dataset, it can be piped

```
dt[, x := mpg][, .(x, mpg)]
```

---

If we want to update the columns in the original object, another option is `set`

```
set(dt[, x:= mpg], i = NULL, j = names(dt)[!names(dt) %in% c('x', 'mpg')], value = NULL)
```

Comment: Which option would be more efficient from the performance perspective? I am assuming that option#1 will require to assign output back to original data table. right? dt <- dt[,.(x = mpg, mpg)]

Comment: @R007 `:=` is faster, but then you are also subsetting.  Can you please check on a bigger dataset with `microbenchmark`